# php matchmaker

Tags: php, tracking

I was thinking it be cool to have a simple matchmaker code in php. The idea is the app connect to the server or a specific webpage, the webpage takes it IP and the last X ips and prints it on page (his first)

problem is what happens when 5 ppl hit the page the same second. How do i handle it? i cant use global/shared memory? so i would need to write the IPs to a file and read/writing them everytime (10x the same second) would be bad? i guess its ok to be slow but i want this to be optimized if possible.

Is it better to store in a mysql db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using APC to memcache the information in memory.. This would only work for 1 server. With multiple servers, you should look at something like memCacheD.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you'd bother doing this, except as a learning exercise, but you're basically going to be persisting the information somewhere, if only for a relatively short time, and you need reasonable transactional semantics.

Probably the simplest option would be to opt for a database; MySQL would be fine, and if you really don't need to store the data for a particularly long time, then you might as well use an in-memory table - use the `MEMORY` (or `HEAP`) storage engine for this. Using a database in this manner means you don't have to worry too much about conflicting concurrent writes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the IP of the requestor in a file - Apache is already doing it for you. Just grep the last lines of the /var/log/httpd/access_log file (if you're on linux) and you'll find the info you need about the last requests received by the server - IP, referer, URL. And they're serialized.

bye!

Comment: That assumes that you're allowed to read the log file, which may not be the case, and that the access log is actually being maintained, which may also not be the case.

Comment: Oh, and it also assumes a fixed log location, which again, is subject to change.